# Is there a name for the diagonal matrix of partial derivatives?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Is there a name or notation for the diagonal matrix of partial derivatives?

If I have a vectors $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & \dotsc & x_n \end{bmatrix}^T$, and  $y = \begin{bmatrix}y_1 & \dotsc & y_n \end{bmatrix}^T$, and I want the vector of partial derivatives, what's the unambiguous way to write that?  If I say $\nabla_x y$, that's the matrix of gradients.  If I say $\nabla_x \cdot y$, that's the trace of the matrix.  I want ${\mathrm{diag}}(\nabla_x y)$ or ${\mathrm{diag}}(\nabla_x) y$.  How should write this?

Comment: What you want to write is the trace of the matrix of gradients? That is called the divergence of the vector $Y$.

Comment: @Jonathaniui No, I specifically wrote that I don't want the trace.  I want the diagonal elements in a vector.

Comment: If you know about differential forms then you may take the coefficientes of the derivative of $Y$ seen as a $n-1$differential form, and you get that vector you want, I don't know if that helps

Comment: @Jonathaniui Thank you.  I don't know about those.  I guess my notation with diag is not really clear :/

Comment: Maybe you can say "we take the diagonal of the gradient matrix as a vector", I don't think that may cause much confussion.

Comment: @Jonathaniui Right, thanks.  In this paper, they just use the partial derivative operator to mean this: http://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/cns/papers/Schraudolph-Tech-99.pdf   .  It seems weird to mix that notation with gradients.